# Bloomberg SWPM Zero Rate Curve Conventions

Tags: swaps, bloomberg, bootstrapping, spot-rate, daycounting

Referencing : [Bloomberg SWPM: Day count to calculate discount factor for US0003M](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/43541/bloomberg-swpm-day-count-to-calculate-discount-factor-for-us0003m#new-answer?newreg=1494b9d8a9804703a1029d5c5e12ad72)

[image: SWPM XCCY Legs]

[image: SWPM XCCY CFs]

Hi,

I have a hard time reproducing the conversions between Discount factors and zero rates for an XCCY Swap I have found in the question referenced.

For rates up to (including) a year, they seem to be simple interest on an Act/360 basis, matching the USD Libor conventions.

Beyond a year though, I can't reproduce the zero rates from the discount factors and vice versa. Neither annual-, S/A-, quarterly-, continuous- compounding, nor simple interest works. I have tried ACT/360 and ACT/ACT for that matter.

Also, it is not a rounding problem.

Comment: Nevermind.... It is actually Bond Basis: 30/360, s/a compounding...